# Google Sheets: Group rows and columns into cells by an ID

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of tasks where rows are grouped using ID's. I want to represent these groupings in another table where there is one row for each ID and all data rows and columns are grouped for each ID in a single cell. I need a formula that can group certain rows into a cell using newlines, and certain columns into cells using delimiters. My data source is something like this:

[image: source table]

The formula needs to:

- Filter rows by `Condition`.
- Put `Task ID`'s in their own column, one row for each *individual* ID.
- Put all data in `Hours`, `Mins`, `Customer` and `Description` columns into a cell next to ID so that:
- - `Hours` and `Mins` are joined with a ":" as a delimiter to represent time values
- - `Customer` and `Description` values are then concatenated to time values using space as a delimiter.

The result should look like:

[image: desired result]

A Google Sheet containing example of the source table and desired result:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14p_HYpfb7XlWhRRgo3JN7SPRerwEaB2A7Dz1KWuBgL8/edit#gid=299935838

Comment: Here is a blank sheet created specifically to help with this question. Paste in the sample data there instead of a screenshot and it will be much easier to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14p_HYpfb7XlWhRRgo3JN7SPRerwEaB2A7Dz1KWuBgL8/edit

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Thanks for the tip, a link to a sheet is now added in the post.

Answer (score 1):

### SUGGESTION:

You can try this custom formula `GROUPDATA` using the script below. Just add it as a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) on your spreadsheet file:

***Script:***

```
function GROUPDATA(data) {
  var temp = "";
  var filtered = [];
  var container = [];
  var col2 =[];
  var final = [];
  data.forEach(function(data) {
    if(data[0] == true){
      filtered.push(data[1])
      container.push([data[1],data[2]+":"+data[3]+" "+data[4]+" "+data[5]])
    }
  });
  const unique = (value,index,self) =>
  {return self.indexOf(value) ===index;}
  var unique_list=filtered.filter(unique);

  for(i=0; i<unique_list.length; i++){
    container.forEach(function(x) {
      if(x[0]== unique_list[i]){
        temp = temp+ x[1]+"\n";
      }
    });
    col2.push(temp);
    temp = "";
  }
  for(y=0; y<unique_list.length; y++){
    final.push([unique_list[y],col2[y]]);
  }
  return final;
}
```

### DEMONSTRATION:

> Used the custom formula `=GROUPDATA(A:F)` on cell `G14`
> [image]